# jQuery "OR" selector with shared modifiers?

Tags: javascript, jquery

For example, is there a shorter way for

```
$("td:nth-child(2),th:nth-child(2)").hide()
```

I tried `$("td,th").hide(":nth-child(2)")` but that doesn't work. Does anyone have ideas about this? Thanks!

Comment: You need to use a filter / find on your query. Within show/hide you can only add options / duration / speed / etc. `.hide( options )` http://api.jquery.com/hide/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

```
$("td,th").filter(":nth-child(2)").hide();
```

---

## .filter(selector)

> **Description:** Reduce the set of matched elements to those that match the selector or pass the function's test.